# Auto redirect in IE not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, redirect, timeout

I have seen similar posts but I haven't get solution.
I have a webpage which displays warning after X minutes and redirects to a logoff.jsp if X+Y=Z minutes.It works well in Chrome/Firefox. While in IE before redirecting to logoff.jsp I'm getting a alert(Stay on this page/leave this page)
[image: Alert I'm reciveing]

Is there a way, which I can redirect with out seeing this alert box ?

Code follows...

> timeOut.js

```
function checkpop() {
    x++;
     if(x==25){
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
        modal.style.display = "none";
        $("iframe").contents().find('#chat').prop('disabled', true);
        //window.location.replace = "logoff.jsp";
        $(location).attr('href', 'http://google.com');
     }
```

Comment: Have you added an `onbeforeunload` event handler somewhere in your code?

Comment: No I didn't @RoryMcCrossan